# Wordpress opening 404 instead of directory

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

So, I have a WP installation in the main web directory of my website. As a sub-directory I have /stats which contains AWStats logs, etc.

When I point to url.com/stats/, instaed of the AWStats page, I get the main WP site with an error 404 page not found.

Could you help me figure out what's causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue recently and this worked for me :

1) make sure your stats folder has the correct permissions, correct user:group and is CHMOD 755 at the max

2) you could create a .htaccess file in your stats folder and add the following line in it

```
Options +Indexes
```

I hope that helped
pardon my english

Comment: Thanks, Arnaud, for taking the time to answer my question. The folder has the correct permissions and I did add `Options +Indexes`, but that didn't seem to change anything - I still get "Page not found" when trying to access /stats. :(

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that the folder is password-protected (.htaccess + .htpasswd_stats).